# Adding a UIControl into title of Navbar Programmatically - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm trying to add a custom UI Segmented control I created into my root view controller's navbar. Here's my code:

Segmented Control:

```
@IBDesignable class FeedViewSC: UIControl {


fileprivate var labels = [UILabel]()
var thumbView = UIView()

var items: [String] = ["Tab1", "Tab2"] {
    didSet {
        setupLabels()
    }

}

var selectedIndex : Int = 0 {
    didSet{
        displayNewSelectedIndex()
    }
}

@IBInspectable var font : UIFont! = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13) {
    didSet {
        setFont()
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupView()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    setupView()
}

func setupView() {

    layer.cornerRadius = 2
    layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 2/255, green: 239/255, blue: 23/255, alpha: 1).cgColor

    backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 239/255, green: 29/255, blue: 239/255, alpha: 1)

    setupLabels()

    insertSubview(thumbView, at: 0)

}


func setupLabels() {
    for label in labels {
        label.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    labels.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)

    for index in 1...items.count {
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
        label.text = items[index-1]
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont(name: "timesnr",size: 17)
        label.textColor = UIColor(red: 51/255, green: 51/255, blue: 51/255, alpha: 1)
        self.addSubview(label)
        labels.append(label)
    }
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    var selectFrame = self.bounds
    let newWidth = selectFrame.width / CGFloat(items.count)
    selectFrame.size.width = newWidth
    thumbView.frame = selectFrame
    thumbView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
    thumbView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    let labelHeight = self.bounds.height
    let labelWidth = self.bounds.width / CGFloat(labels.count)

    for index in 0...labels.count - 1 {

        let label = labels[index]

        let xPosition = CGFloat(index) * labelWidth
        label.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: labelWidth, height: labelHeight)
    }

}

override func beginTracking(_ touch: UITouch, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let location = touch.location(in: self)

    var calculatedIndex: Int?
    for (index, item) in labels.enumerated() {
        if item.frame.contains(location){
            calculatedIndex = index
        }
    }
    if calculatedIndex != nil {
        selectedIndex = calculatedIndex!
        sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
    }

    return false

}


func displayNewSelectedIndex (){

    if(self.selectedIndex == -1){
        self.selectedIndex = self.items.count-1
    }

    let label = labels[selectedIndex]
}

func setFont(){
    for item in labels {
        item.font = font
    }
}

}
```

My VC that I would liek to add this Segmented Control to:

```
class FeedViewController: UIViewController {


let feedViewSC: FeedViewSC = {
    let sc = FeedViewSC()
    sc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return sc
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    view.addSubview(feedViewSC)
    setupFeedViewSC()
}

func setupFeedViewSC() {
    feedViewSC.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    feedViewSC.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    feedViewSC.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
    feedViewSC.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 60).isActive = true
    feedViewSC.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -60).isActive = true
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let img = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = img
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(img, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

If you can tell me how I can add my custom UIControl to my View Controller's Navigation bar title.

Comment: You can also do it in storyboard. drag a uiview on top of navigation bar and change class name as FeedViewSC . You can resize up to your need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the FeedViewController is the initial view controller of the NavigationController you can do it very simply by

```
let feedControl = FeedViewSC(frame: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds)!)
feedControl.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(feedControl)
feedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FeedViewController.changingTab), for: .valueChanged)
```

At least I don't see a reason that this would not work for getting it in the navigation bar.

Also not part of the question but if you are having any trouble seeing your control in IB might I suggest.

```
override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    layer.cornerRadius = 2
    layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 2/255, green: 239/255, blue: 23/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 239/255, green: 29/255, blue: 239/255, alpha: 1)
    setupLabels()
    insertSubview(thumbView, at: 0)
}
```

As for the control itself I did not test it but your events and your handling may be slightly different than value changed I am not sure.

You could also make the navigation bar of the controller a special designable class and never add it in code but you would probably have to get a reference in the viewDidLoad to use it.  The designable would look like

```
import UIKit

    @IBDesignable class DesignableNavBar: UINavigationBar {

        var feedControl : FeedViewSC!

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)

            setupView()
        }

        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: coder)
            setupView()
        }

        func setupView() {
            if feedControl == nil{
                feedControl = NavControl(frame: self.bounds)
                feedControl.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight,.flexibleWidth]
                self.addSubview(feedControl)
            }

        }

        override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
            super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
            setupView()
        }


    }
```

And then in your controller in say the viewDidLoad you could do this.

```
if let navController = self.navigationController{
        if navController.navigationBar is DesignableNavBar{
            let control = (navController.navigationBar as! DesignableNavBar). feedControl
            control?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.changingTab), for: .valueChanged)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know you marked this correct I updated it if you want to be able to see it in your navigation controller.  just change the navbar in the uinavigationcontroller to match the class above then it will be designable in the storyboard in the navigation bar.  Enjoy